# deployment typescript react project error not show website

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deployment, vercel

page lang detection: 67ms - timer ended fpTranslator.js:5407:21
TypeError: data.languages[0] is undefined
vercel deployment error not show website
react+typescript+redux-toolkit project is loaded successfully but  showing a white page please help me